# Solve the system : $ x^2 + x - 1 = y $, $ y^2 + y - 1 = z $, $ z^2 + z - 1 = x $ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations in x,y,z : $ x^2 + x - 1 = y $ , $ y^2 + y - 1 = z $, $ z^2 + z - 1 = x $ .

I'd tried analysing various manipulations but can't figure out .

**What I've tried:**
$$ x^2 + x - 1 = y \ ...(1)$$ $$ y^2 + y - 1 = z \ ...(2)$$ $$ z^2 + z - 1 = x \ ...(3)$$

From (1), (2) and (3) , $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3 $ 
From (1), $ x(x+1) = y+1 $ & $ (x+1)(x-1) = y-x $ 
From (2), $ y(y+1) = z+1 $ & $ (y+1)(y-1) = z-y $ 
From (3), $ z(z+1) = x+1 $ & $ (z+1)(z-1) = x-z $ 
Any way it's quite obvious to see that $ x = y = z = 1 $ is one of the possible solutions.
But no idea how to use these informations to get all the possible values of x,y and z .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know
$$ x^2 + x - 1 = y 
\implies x(1+x) = 1 +y  $$
Similarly
$$ y^2 + y - 1 = z 
\implies y(1+y) = 1 +z  $$
$$ z^2 + z - 1 = x 
\implies z(1+z) = 1 +x  $$
Substituting this value of $1+x$ in the 1st equation, we get
$$ xz(1+z) = 1 + y$$
Again substituting this in the second equation, we get,
$$ xyz(1+z) = 1 + z$$
This basically implies either $z = -1$ or $xyz = 1$
Assuming $z = -1$ we get
$$x = (-1)^2 -1 -1 = -1$$
Similarly, $y = -1$
Thus, clearly $(-1,-1,-1)$ is a solution.
Now in the second case, we have $xyz = 1$
Also, as you have correctly pointed out, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$.
Thus we can say,
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3\times 1 = 3xyz$$
$$\implies (x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx) = 0$$
This is possible if and only if $x=y=z$ or if $x+y+z=0$.
Considering $x=y=z$,
we get, $x^3 = 1$. Hence for real values of x, $x = y = z = 1$. If you include complex values, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ also satisfy the condition $xyz = 1$.
Hence these are also valid solutions.
Now, let's consider the other case where $x + y + z = 0$.

Then,
$$x + y + \frac{1}{xy} = 0 \implies y = \frac{-x^2 \pm \sqrt{x^4 - 4x}}{2x}$$
This expression can be used to solve for x, and hence for y and z.

Comment: Nice observation 

Comment: Something wrong with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3\times 1 = 3xyz$
$\implies (x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx) = 0$ since $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz= (x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx)$. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 5):

Set $f(t) = t^2+t-1$. Then $x, y, z$ are solutions of the equation
$$
 0 = f(f(f(t))) - t = (t-1)(t+1)(t^6+4t^5+5t^4+2t^3+1) \, .
$$
The last factor $g(t) = t^6+4t^5+5t^4+2t^3+1$ has no real zeros, $g$ attains a positive global minimum at $t = (\sqrt{13}-7)/6$.

It follows that $x=y=z=1$ and $x=y=z=-1$ are the only real solutions.